# Does the past simple work here in my example?

Tags: past-tense

> Did not know that you would contact me again!!!

> I had tried to contact someone so many times and did not receive an answer that I had completely forgotten that I had made an order.

I think it is better without the last *had* in *had made* because it is obvious that before contacting you and forgetting my order I have placed it. I want only  emphasize  the forgetting

Comment: Off-topic: *to contact* is transitive, so you need *to contact **you***

Comment: "I wasn't expecting you to contact me again."

Comment: No, it doesn't work because you're not writing sentences. The first one is missing a subject. The second one is missing an indirect object.

Comment: Which sentence is your question exactly? Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 1):

> I had tried to contact so many times and did not receive an answer
> that I had completely forgotten that I( had) made an order

Using the past perfect here implies that this entire situation preceded something else.  I guess the person received an order they were no longer expecting.

The sentence should be:

I **tried** to contact **you** so many times and **did** not receive an answer that I had completely forgotten that I **had** made an order.

or

I **had tried** to contact **you** so many times and **had** not receive**d** an answer that I had completely forgotten that I **had** made an order

The first option explains what you did and then refers to the prior situation that makes receiving the order a surprise.  The second option describes the entire pre-existing situation as explaining the reason for the surprise.

Comment: If in fact I didn't  receive the order but only was surprised to get an answer from the seller. Is the first solution better?

Comment: The second focuses more on the fact that your attempts to contact were in vain and so gave you a disappointing result.  If you are just surprised to get a late answer, then the first is better since it puts emphasis only on the forgetting.

Comment: but if I choose the first one , is the meaning a bit ambiguous? Since the attempt to contact the seller ended  with the receipt of the email . If I  choose past simple for try there is a chance to understand that the attempt to contact the seller starts after not before the receipt of the email. Past perfect is better to make sure the event is before .